# Flask API gives URL not found error for spesific URl

Tags: python, api, flask

I have my API like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import db

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return "flask mongodb atlas!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000)

@app.route('/text')
def text():
    return "This is a text"
```

When I try to run it in local host (http://127.0.0.1:8000) and test the `/home` url it gives me correct results but when I try `/text` it gives me URL not found error in the site and following error in the cmd:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Oct/2021 02:21:37] "GET /text HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Oct/2021 02:22:06] "GET /text HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Oct/2021 02:26:22] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I don't think there is any syntax error's but I don't get where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from flask import Flask
import db

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return "flask mongodb atlas!"

@app.route('/text')
def text():
    return "This is a text"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000)
```

You need define all your app before is started